# How to make object with no values given? And put a value on it with user input in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

We are asked to make object of person that has a properties of name, age, height with no values in it. For it to have a value we need to ask it from the user using prompt.

```
    var person = {
    name: null,
    age: null,
    height: null
    };
    /** If the properties has null values then how can I put a value in it
    by getting user input? **/
```

Comment: Can you please explain your real Question...?

Comment: why not initialize with `''` or `undefined`

Comment: Set the values to `undefined`…?

Comment: `{name: null, age: null, height: null}`?

Comment: null value properties, so how can I put a value on that property from a user input?

Comment: Depends… how will you *take* the user input? If that's your actual question, then lead with that.

Comment: Prompt where? Browser or node?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the values to `null` to begin with. `undefined` would also do as well, *if* you're not stringifying it to JSON, otherwise it'll be removed.

```
var person = { 
  name: null,
  age: null,
  height: null
};
```

Note that checks using `in` to see if the key exists will still return `true`, so if you want to make it seem like the key doesn't exist, it's sometimes better if it *literally* does not exist in the object.

Comment: if it is in null value how can I put a value in it from a user input using prompt?

Comment: `person.name = prompt("Please enter your name")`.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this should explain why. Out of all the answers, it's the only one that mentioned why `null` should be preferred against `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you for your support @briosheje. Also to answer the OP's question, you can also use `alert(person.name)` to show the new value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var person = {
    name: null ,
     age: null ,
     height: null   
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var person = {
    name:"JK",
    love:"Loli!!!!!!!!!!!!!",
    };

if("love" in person){
  if(person["love"]=="Loli!!!!!!!!!!!!!"){
    console.log("Call FBI");
  }
}else{
  //Do Something Input What you want like
  //person["love"]=??
}
if("height" in person){

}else{
   person["height"]= prompt("Enter Your Height");
  
}


console.log(person);
```

Try it don't call FBI!

Answer (score -1):

first create an object:
    var person = {}
    then you can try with it person.name = document.getElementById('name').value
    then for rest you can do the same